# Storing data in-between segues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tableView, it is populated with car names. User can add, delete cells.
`CarData.swift`:

```
struct CarData {
    var name: String
}
```

`Cars.swift`:

```
class Cars{
    var list = [
        CarData(name: "Toyota Corolla"),
        CarData(name: "BMW 3")
    ]
}
```

`ListViewController.swift`:

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var carsList = Cars()
    var cars = [CarData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        cars = carsList.list
    .
    .
    .
```

When a segue brings user to the `ListViewController`, the list is always going to be the same due to the way `cars` array is initialized. What I want is the list to save its data in-between segues and not to be rewritten every time. I have a lot of segues, so sending `cars` array all around doesn't seem to be a great idea. What should I do?

Comment: declare your `list` static and access it like `Cars.list`

Comment: You're the man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Global Access!

For your begging level, you can create a singleton object to access it globally across the entire application.

```
class CarsManager
{
    // MARK: Init

    private init() { }

    // MARK: Properties

    static var shared = CarsManager()
    private var cars: [CarData] = []

    // MARK: Methods

    func addNewCar(_ car: CarData)
    {
        cars.append(car)
    }
    
    func getCars() -> [CarData]
    {
        return cars
    }
}
```

### Usage

You can add cars to your list on any screen:

```
let someCar = CarData(name: "Toyota Corolla")
CarsManager.shared.addNewCar(someCar)
```

Then you can easily access your list from all screens:

```
CarsManager.shared.getCars()
```

### What to do next?

You should read more about the pros and cons of the singleton design pattern to know when to use and when not:

- [What Is a Singleton and How To Create One In Swift](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift)
- [Singleton in Swift](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/swift/example)
- [Swift Singletons: A Design Pattern to Avoid (With Examples)](https://matteomanferdini.com/swift-singleton/)